# Correct way to use the Normal Map node in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

The Node Map usage in the first case looks correct and crisp:

[image]

But second case looks inverted and crumpled:

[image]

Why the second way doesn't work?
I use the purple normal map and follow [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/rPxPWqj99kA?t=3m37s)

Comment: In the First one you used Displacement,  but in Second one you used Normal map.

Comment: Don't mix diffuse and glossy with add node - that breaks energy conservation. Use mix shader. Also for color use *Color* and not *Non-Color-Data*. The second setup for normal map is correct but your normal texture map is wrong. Some are left-handed some are right-handed, you need to use the right kind for blender. All are purple btw.